# Ubuntu 18.04 Screen Flickering on Dell XPS 15 9570 GTX 1050 Ti

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, 18.04, flicker

Just trying out Linux for the first time. I am able to install Ubuntu 18.04 without any problem except for the fact that my screen keeps on spontaneously flickering. It starts to flicker as soon as the system boots up to the login screen (even before entering my password).

Things tried:

- Changing between different drivers in the Software & Updates ->
  Additional Drivers option (nvidia-driver-396, nvidia-driver-390,
  nouveau)
- Boot with "nomodeset"
- Blacklist nouveau
- Updating kernel to 4.17.4

If there anything else I should try please let me know.

[image: Additional Drivers option screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same flickering problem. It was solved by upgrading the kernel to v4.17.14.
Kernel version 4.17.12 also seems to be fine as described in https://base64.co.za/ubuntu-18-04-on-dell-xps-9570/