# Running any linux distribution results in screen flicker on DELL XPS 15 9570

Tags: nvidia, dell, 19.10, xps

From what I have seen this issue is a "little bit" outdated and it seems like people have stopped having this problem. However, I am trying to install Ubuntu 19.10 on the Dell XPS 15 and it always results in screen flicker. I cannot find any more solutions to my problem so I have decided to ask a question directly.

CPU :Intel Core i5-8300H

GPU :NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050 (4GB GDDR5)

I have tried to do everything that is mentioned in this post:
[Ubuntu 18.04 Screen Flickering on Dell XPS 15 9570 GTX 1050 Ti](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1056218/ubuntu-18-04-screen-flickering-on-dell-xps-15-9570-gtx-1050-ti) (Note: my laptop contains GTX 1050 graphics and not 1050Ti)

The only way to get past this issue is to set `nomodeset` in the grub parameters (This would have been satisfactory however, the OS will take about 60 seconds longer to start and I cannot set the brightness of the screen. This problem also occurs if I try to boot any other Linux distros (I have tried Arch and POP!_OS)). (The issue does not occur in Windows)

I have tried downgrading my kernel to the suggested versions (4.17.4 and 4.20)

I have tried using the suggested script posted on github : https://github.com/JackHack96/dell-xps-9570-ubuntu-respin

I have also tried to blacklist nouveau however, the issue does not seem to be driver related

If anyone has any suggestions to how I could solve my problem it would be greatly appreciated

`dkms status` output: `nvidia, 435.21, 5.3.0-18-generic, x86_64: installed`

Comment: You only use nomodeset until you install nVidia driver from Ubuntu repository. Do not install directly from nVidia with .run file. And if incorrect nVidia driver or you change drivers you must purge old before installing new. Have you updated UEFI & SSD firmware? https://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/how-do-i-install-the-nvidia-drivers List drivers so you know whichis newest? `dpkg -l | grep -i nvidia`  and Whats installed: `dkms status` https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2362351&p=13649946#post13649946

Comment: The UEFI & SSD firmware is up to date. I have updated the nVidia drivers from the ubuntu repository removing nomodeset still causes the same issue. I have also used `prime-select intel` which primed my intel graphics the issue persists if I remove nomodeset

Comment: So both Intel & nVidia give screen flicker issues? Did you totally purge any older nVidia drivers before updating?

Comment: Yes both nVidia and Intel result in screen flickers. Purging previously installed drivers does not resolve the issue either.

Comment: Not sure what issue may be. Post this above in question. `dkms status`

Comment: Added `dkms status` output

Comment: That should be a good driver, and Dell typically just works if driver installed. Is there something specific your are doing? If you open top or htop which you have to install, is some other process running away when flicker starts?

Comment: It seems like the flicker starts as soon as the boot loader loads the OS, so I cant really tell.

Comment: Do you still have nomodeset in grub? That can create conflicts with nVidia. Otherwise I am out of ideas.

Comment: If I don't have nomodeset I cannot tell what is going on on the screen. I have tried both with nomodeset and without nomodeset, without using nomodeset the issue persists.

Comment: I have no more suggestions. You could try 20.04, realizing it will not be final until April, will have many updates and could break if updates out of order. And with so many updates you may want to plan on new install when released just to houseclean cruft. I am posting from 20.04, although on my system 18.04 os main working install. Keep /home separate to make it easier to install to your / (root) partition.